# Неожиданно появившаяся новая интернет-страница

Tags: windows

Неожиданно появился в адресе и открывается интернетная страница http://smartinf.ru/

Как от нее можно избавиться?

Пользуюсь Firefox. Когда открываю, выскакивает smahninf.ru, пыталась поменять стартовую страницу через инструменты - ничего не получается. Я не могу найти, где ее можно удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет всем, я нашел эту гадость в реестре:

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1697932951-1538109606-3763280777 1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"pyggoseemg"="cmd /c start http://simsimotkroysia.ru/"
```

Удалив этот параметр, вы навсегда избавитесь от этого, вы также можете изменить страницу, например, на www.google.ru

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, но как мне найти этот реестр....Я не очень сильна в програмировании....

Comment: @Nina Данный ответ аналог моего 2-го пункта (У товарищей сталкивался...). [Посмотрите видео, как это сделать](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNn52VdB1Cw)

Как вариант, в редакторе реестра (`regedit`) нажмите `Ctrl+F` и воспользуйтесь поиском вашей беды `smartinf.ru`.

> Я не очень сильна в програмировании

Здесь совершенно не в программировании дело.

Comment: так я это делала и ничего не нашла, но попробую еще раз....

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое, посмотрите в [автозагрузке](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rlwi4ExkzgM) - нет ничего странного? Если всё норм, то сценарий посложнее - необходимо смотреть процессы.

- [Вариант с добавлением в симлинк/ярлык](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHMevI-awsE)
- У товарищей сталкивался [с такой вот неприятностью](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNn52VdB1Cw)

Comment: Вот у меня винда, и что? Нет, вирусы и малварь под винду есть потому, что это самая распространённая десктопная система.

Comment: @VladD, я никого не хотел обидеть. Я с Вами полностью согласен.

Comment: @romeo: В любом случае, ваш ответ по существу.

Answer (score 0):

Самое главное, это засечь редирект, который потом выбрасывает на smahninf.ru. Когда начинает загружать браузер, нужно увидеть, какая ссылка появляется сначала на этой странице. В моем случае это был foretuned.com. Это может быть simsimotkroysia.ru, или manluky.ru, или что-то другое, но в реестре нужно удалять ссылку именно на этот сайт.

Избавляемся от него так: командная строка -- > regedit -- >правка -- > найти    пишем в строку foretuned.com (manlucky.ru или simsimotkroysia.ru то, что появилось именно у вас)  -- > найти.

Как завершится поиск, ищем файл, подписанный в Значении как `cmd/c start http://foretuned.com/` и удаляем его. Опять же, каждый ищет с названием своего редиректа.
Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь ярлык, которым ты запускаешь FF - в нём может быть задан параметр с url, тогда соответствующий адрес будет открываться при каждом запуске.